# MS Access SQL left join giving all 0

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join

I am trying to make a summary table of all the items I have. I have a raw data table with 10 users who respectively have different items. There are maximum 3 different items and I want to do a count to see how many items each individual has. The following is my code.

```
Select b.Country,b.UserID,Num_including_fruits, Apple,Orange
from

(((SELECT o.Country,o.UserID, IIF(ISNULL(Count(o.UserID)),0,Count(o.UserID))
 AS Num_including_fruits
 FROM [SEA2_View] as o
 GROUP BY o.UserID, o.Country
 ORDER BY Country)as b

 LEFT JOIN

 (SELECT o.Country,o.UserID,IIF(ISNULL(Count(o.UserID)),0,Count(o.UserID)
    AS Apple
  FROM [APAC2_View] as o
  WHERE o.fruit_status <>"fresh" AND o.HWType = "Apple"
  GROUP BY o.Country,o.UserID)as d

  ON (b.UserID = d.UserID))

  LEFT JOIN

   (SELECT o.Country,o.UserID,IIF(ISNULL(Count(o.UserID)),0,Count(o.UserID))
    AS Orange
    FROM [SEA2_View] as o
    WHERE o.fruit_status <>"fresh" AND o.HWType = "Orange"
    GROUP BY o.Country,o.UserID)as e
    ON (d.UserID = e.UserID))
   ;
```

The first join returns the correct result but the second join somehow returns all 0, which is incorrect. Therefore please help! and I would appreciate any advice for best practice when it comes to joins in SQL. Thanks lot!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have a table naming error?

You're first joining **[SEA2_View]** with **[APAC2_View]**. The second join is joining with **[SEA2_View]** with itself.